# Vagrant Oracle ORA-12541: TNS:no listener' in /var/www/core/db.class.php

Tags: php, macos, oracle, oracle11g, vagrant

I've finished configuring a Vagrant box with oracle 11G.

I've tested the connection using SqlDeveloper from my local MAC machine and all seems fine `(ssm_android -> localhost 1521 xe)`.

What I really need is to connect to this Oracle DB through PHP.

Here's my Vagrant config for the oracle machine (I added some relevant info below):

```
vagrant@oracle:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin$ echo $ORACLE_HOME 
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe

vagrant@oracle:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin$ echo $ORACLE_SID  
XE

vagrant@oracle:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin$ vi listener.ora 

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)

vagrant@oracle:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin$ vi tnsnames.ora

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

vagrant@oracle:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 16-FEB-2015 13:26:37

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                16-FEB-2015 11:34:27
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 52 min. 10 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracle/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracle)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

And here's the error i get in PHP when I try connecting using the following data

```
user = "ssm_android"
host = "127.0.0.1:1521/XE"
password = "xxxxxxx"
database = "XE"
```

:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Cannot
>   connect to database: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener' in
>   /var/www/core/db.class.php:164 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/core/db.class.php(113): Db->connect('ssm_android',
>   'NtakmdVSYgsYSNii11...', '127.0.0.1:1521/...') #1 /var/www/index.php(56):
>   Db->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/core/db.class.php on
>   line 164

Could be relevant the fact that the machine running the php is another local Vagrant machine mapped to localhost... not sure..

I'd appreciate any insight on this.

Thanks.

Comment: test on the db machine, whether the listener is running: `lstnrctl status`. start it with `lstnrctl start`.

Comment: [edted] to include listener status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the whole problem was that both vagrant machines were configured   with dynamic ips. Changing vagrant config files to include static ips did the trick.